# Multiple TikZ pictures in standalone file but output only one

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

Can I have multiple TikZ pictures in one standalone file and control which one of them is inserted via some argument or option passed to `\includestandalone{<standalone file>}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\includestandalone` accepts the same arguments as `\includegraphics` according to the manual, so you should be able to do

```
\includestandalone[page=2]{diagrams}
```

to include the second page/diagram.

With `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` in `diagrams.tex`, each `tikzpicture` environment becomes a separate page.

Comment: Just what I had in mind. Works great!