# Alternatives to tikzexternalize

Tags: pgfplots, external-files, tikz-external, externalize

I know this may sound too broad, but: is there any alternative approach to `tikzexternalize` out there?
Especially when using `pgfplots`.

At least for me, it is not always easy/straightforward to have the externalization process behave properly, especially with large documents.

The minimum requirement is at least to generate the graphics file to be included in the main document without creating ad additional `.tex` file with `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`.

Comment: You realize that all externalize does is run standalone as a separate job (shell escape).

Comment: Yes I do, and either I run `pdflatex -shell-escape` explicitly from the cli, or I configure the latextools builder to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en) package where you can have varieties of the externalization process via `mode` option as quoted from the [documentation](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}

\begin{filecontents*}{myplot.tex}
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[ultra thick, domain=0:10]
                \addplot [red] {x};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{figure}
        \includestandalone[mode = buildnew]{myplot}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this looks very promising :)

Comment: this took a while, but I eventually deployed it :)
It is also interesting to note the existence of the `page` option of `\includestandalone` as pointed out in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393539/177.
Accepted!